# Xcode 5 Dynamically Adjust Font Size Multiple Labels

Tags: ios, xcode, dynamic, fonts, size

My Xcode 5 project has a label where the User enters a string of numbers.  That string is then sent to one of two other labels (either labelA or labelB) by the User pressing one of two buttons.  Font size in both labelA and labelB are dynamically resized (if necessary) using:

```
_labelA.numberOfLines = 1;
_labelA.minimumScaleFactor = 8./_inchesDisplayLabel.font.pointSize;
_labelA.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

and:

```
_labelB.numberOfLines = 1;
_labelB.minimumScaleFactor = 8./_inchesDisplayLabel.font.pointSize;
_labelB.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

If a string in labelA gets resized to fit within the label, how can the font size in labelB be programmatically resized to match the smaller resized font in labelA?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After `labelA`'s font gets resized, use this to make `labelB`'s font match `labelA`'s:

```
[labelB setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:labelA.font.fontName size:labelA.font.pointSize]];
```